IonViewDidEnter called twice on startup
I was wondering if you could me with this task. I have tried a few suggestions from similar threads I've found and tried some I could easily detect, but I couldn't really relate others to my situation, so perhaps you can help me in my particular case.
The issue here is that the ionViewDidEnter hook is triggered twice once the app is launched (however, it doesn't do that afterwards, for example, if you navigate to other pages and come back, it will correctly only trigger once). I'll put the html and ts code here so for more clarity. If more info is needed, please let me know! Cheers everyone
HTML:
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Join an Event</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
      
 
<ion-content>
  <div padding text-center *ngIf="!hasVerifiedEmail">
    Please verify your email to view the events!
    <ion-button (click)="sendVerificationEmail()">Send verification email</ion-button><br>
    Click refresh if you have verified!
    <ion-button (click)="pageReload()">Refresh</ion-button>
  </div>
  
<div *ngIf="hasVerifiedEmail">

  <ion-searchbar mode="ios"  placeholder="Search Event by Name" show-clear-button="always" showCancelButton="focus" (ionChange)="searchField($event)"></ion-searchbar> <!--  (ionCancel)="getUserPrefs()" -->

  <h6>Filter Events by Sport/Activity</h6>
  <ion-slides class="categories-slides" [options]="catSlideOptions">
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('All')"><img src="assets/img/cat-all.jpg"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('Soccer')"><img src="assets/img/cat-soccer.jpg"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('Basketball')"><img src="assets/img/cat-basketball.jpg"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('Tennis')"><img src="assets/img/cat-tennis.jpg"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('Gym')"><img src="assets/img/cat-gym.jpg"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (click)="changeSportPreference('Running')"><img src="assets/img/cat-running.jpg"></ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

  <h6>Find a Place (Coming Soon!)</h6>
  <ion-slides [options]="placesOptions">

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-card><img src="assets/img/pitch-smithfield.jpg">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>Smithfield Astro Pitch</ion-card-title>
          <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="comingSoonAlert()"><ion-card-subtitle>Book Now</ion-card-subtitle></ion-button>
      </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
      <ion-card><img src="assets/img/pitch-example.jpg">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>Example Astro Pitch</ion-card-title>
          <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="comingSoonAlert()"><ion-card-subtitle>Book Now</ion-card-subtitle></ion-button>
      </ion-card-header>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>

  <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="toggleFilteredEvents()"><ion-card-subtitle>{{ showFilteredEvents ? "Show All Events" : "Show Events Within 5km" }}</ion-card-subtitle></ion-button>

  
  <!-- Modified this for Pagination test 2, copy code from repo to backup -->
  <ion-list *ngIf="itemsPage!==undefined">
    <h6>Events Available</h6>
     <ion-card *ngFor="let evt of (showFilteredEvents ? eventsWithin5Km : itemsPage)" padding style="background: url('../../../assets/img/gameon-tennis-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;"> 
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-card-subtitle>{{ evt.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}, at {{ evt.date | date:'h:mm a'}}</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-title>{{ evt.type }}</ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle>{{ evt.title }}</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-subtitle><ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>{{ evt.location }}</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-subtitle>Participants: <span class="numPart"> {{ evt.part.length }}</span> / <span class="numPlayers">{{ evt.players }}</span></ion-card-subtitle>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="viewEventDetails(evt)">View Event</ion-button>
          <!-- <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="addMeToEvent(evt)">Join Event</ion-button> -->
          <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="joinEvent(evt)">Join Event</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
     </ion-card>
  </ion-list>

  <div *ngIf="itemsPage?.length<=0" class="ion-padding">
    <ion-item class="ion-text-center txtAlert" lines="none">
      No events available for this category
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="ion-text-center txtAlert" lines="none">
     <ion-label><ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="userCurrentPreferredSport('All')">View All</ion-button> or <ion-button small expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="createEvent()">Create one!</ion-button></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
  

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="80px" (ionInfinite)="loadDataInfiniteScrolling($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles" 
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

</div>
</ion-content>

TS:
constructor(
    private eventServ: EventsService,
    private alertServ: AlertService,
    private userServ: UsersService,
    private pushServ: PushService,
    private authServ: AuthService,
    public loadServ: LoadService,
    private router: Router,
    private locationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy, // GPS and Geolocation for User and Events
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute // GPS and Geolocation for User and Events
  ){
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }


  async ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log('ionViewDidEnter() called');
    
    this.loadServ.presentLoad();
    
    this.events = []
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '{}');

    this.getUserProfile();
    this.userModel = {};
    this.getCurrentLocation();

    // ADDED TO ATTEMPT TO TRY TO CALCULATE USERS AND EVENT DISTANCE
    this.eventLocation = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('eventLocation');
    this.userLocation = null;

    console.log("the user has verified his email.");

  }

  getUserProfile() {
    this.userServ.getUserProfile(this.currentUser['user']['uid']).then((doc: any) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.user = this.currentUser;
        this.tempUser = doc.data();
        this.userModel = this.tempUser;
        this.userName = this.userModel.name ?? " ";
        this.userFavSport = this.userModel.pref ?? 'all';
      } else {
        console.log("getUserProfile failed");
      }
      this.listEvents(this.userFavSport);
    });
  }

  // Setting and changing the User's preferred Sport
  userCurrentPreferredSport(userFavSport?: any) {
    this.index = 0;
    let localPref: any;
    console.log('PrefArray:', userFavSport);
  
    if (userFavSport !== undefined) {
      localPref = userFavSport;
    } else if (this.userFavSport !== undefined) {
      localPref = this.userFavSport;
    } else {
      localPref = 'All';
    }
    console.log('localPref:', localPref); // debugging
  
    if (localPref == 'All') {
      // Load all events when "All" is selected
      // Filter to include all data types
      this.itemsPage = this.events.slice(this.index, this.index + this.offset);
      this.index += this.offset;
    } else {
      let prefItemsPage = this.events.filter((item: any) => {
        if (localPref == 'All') {
          // Include all data types when localPref is "All"
          return true;
        } else {
          return item.type === localPref;
        }
      });
      console.log('prefItemsPage:', prefItemsPage); // debugging
  
      // Load the initial set of events based on user preference
      this.itemsPage = prefItemsPage.slice(this.index, this.index + this.offset);
      this.index += this.offset;
    }
  
    // Check if there are more events to load
    this.checkIndexToLoad();
    
  }

  changeSportPreference(selectedSport: string) {
    this.userFavSport = selectedSport; // Update the user's sport preference
    this.userCurrentPreferredSport(this.userFavSport); // Call the preference function to load events of the selected sport
  }

  // Infinite Scrolling
  async checkIndexToLoad() {
    if (this.index < this.events.length) {
      // Enable infinite scrolling if there are more events to load
      this.infiniteScroll!.disabled = false;
    } else {
      // Disable infinite scrolling if no more events are available
      this.infiniteScroll!.disabled = true;
    }
  }

  scrollHandler(e:any) {
    console.log("e: ", e);
    if (e === 'bottom') {
      //this.page.more()
    }
  }

  async loadDataInfiniteScrolling(event: any) {
    this.reActiveInfinite = event;
  
    console.log('loadData called. userFavSport: ', this.userFavSport);
  
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Load more events based on the user's current sport preference
      let filteredEvents = [];
  
      if (this.userFavSport === 'All') {
        // Load more events without sport type filtering when 'All' is selected
        filteredEvents = this.events;
      } else {
        // Load more events based on the user's current sport preference
        filteredEvents = this.events.filter((event: any) => {
          return event.type === this.userFavSport;
        });
      }
  
      const moreEvents = filteredEvents.slice(this.index, this.index + this.offset);
  
      this.index += this.offset;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < moreEvents.length; i++) {
        this.itemsPage.push(moreEvents[i]);
      }
  
      event.target.complete();
  
      // Check if there are more events to load
      this.checkIndexToLoad();
    }, 1000);
  }

  // Page reload after user verifies email
  pageReload(){
    window.location.reload();
  }

  // Search Field (top bar)
  async searchField(event: any) {    
    this.itemsPage = await this.eventServ.initializeEvents();
    const searchTerm = event.srcElement.value;

    if (!searchTerm) { 
        return;
    }

    this.itemsPage = this.itemsPage.filter((currentEvent: any) => {
        return (
            currentEvent.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
            currentEvent.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        );
    });
}


  // Events-related functions (List, View, Create, Join)
  async listEvents(pref: any){
    this.eventServ.listEvents().subscribe(async (res: any[])=>{

      this.events = res.map(e => {
        
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          createdAt: e.payload.doc.data()['createdAt'],
          createdBy: e.payload.doc.data()['createdBy'],
          part: e.payload.doc.data()['part'],
          comments: e.payload.doc.data()['comments'],
          type: e.payload.doc.data()['type'],
          title: e.payload.doc.data()['title'],
          date: e.payload.doc.data()['date'],
          time: e.payload.doc.data()['time'],
          map: e.payload.doc.data()['map'],
          players: e.payload.doc.data()['players'],
          location: e.payload.doc.data()['location'],
          description: e.payload.doc.data()['description'],
          image: e.payload.doc.data()['image'],
        } as Event;        
      }) 
      
      console.log('Events => ', this.events);
      if(this.events.length>0){
        this.userCurrentPreferredSport(pref);

      }
    });
    
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.loadServ.dismissLoad();
    }, 1000);
  }
}


This is a lot of code.  Please provide the minimum code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Maybe there is some additional router event happening causing the component to leave and come back (like an auth flow or something).

does the load service have a redirect to the same page? (this.loadServ.presentLoad();)

Hi @BizzyBob thanks for the heads up, yes I removed some code that are not necessary for this issue! Regarding router events, perhaps I'm unable to catch that, but it makes sense to be related to an auth flow as the first time you launch we do verify if the user is logged in/authenticated, but as far as I can tell we just retrieve the accessToken from localStorage? Would you like me to paste some other code for the auth?

@MostafaHarb no it doesn't, here's the presentLoad():
async presentLoad(){
this.loading = await this.loadCtrl.create({
spinner: 'bubbles',
message: 'Loading Events...',
translucent: true,
cssClass: 'custom-class custom-loading',
backdropDismiss: true
});
await this.loading.present();
}

Create a reproducible example in stackblitz for quicker assistance.
